# Place content of a Div at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an input that holds an integer value. The input value will be increased by 1 if the `caret-up` button is clicked and decrease by 1 if the `cater-down` button is clicked.

My problem is the style of the `down-caret` is wrong. I would like to place the `down-caret` at the top of the **blue** rectangle.

Currently, the `down-caret` is at the bottom of the div. Below is an image of the currently output.

[image]

I tried several things like flex, absolute position, etc. But these are overlapping areas of the Red div and Blue div.

```js
// add a javascript function to change the value of the input when clicking the caret
// get the input element
var input = document.getElementById("remind_number");
// function to modify the value of the input
function addValue(value) {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) + parseInt(value);
}
```

```css
/* style the qty div to display both input and buttons div in the same line*/
.qty {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

/* add the wrapper div to easy styling the element*/
#remind_number_wrapper {
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

/* adjust the height of the input to fit out the div parent, it easier to see*/
#remind_number_wrapper input {
 width: 220px;
 height: 100%;
}

/* style the buttons div to display input and caret in the same line*/
#buttons {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

/* style the action button to fit the height of the div*/
.action_btn {
  height: 25px;
}

#plus_remind {
    font: 33px/1 Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#minus_remind {   
    font: 33px/1 Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="qty">
   <div id="remind_number_wrapper">
     <input placeholder="Remind Number" name="remind_number" class="form-control" type="text" id="remind_number" value="0">
   </div>
   <div id="buttons">
     <!-- add className 'action_btn' to easier to style button in the same place-->
     <div class="action_btn" id="plus_remind" onclick="addValue(1)">
        <!-- change the fas to fa for the right class of font-awesome -->
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="action_btn" id="minus_remind" onclick="addValue(-1)">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or some other option.

Comment: Hi, I've converted your code to a snippet so that we can see it in action - unfortunately, your snippet doesn't match your image. Please provide the correct and complete css to generate the screenshot so that we can help amend it.  See [mcve].

Comment: @ArpitBansal better to recommend a snippet rather than jsfiddle - jsfiddle is a 3rd party site and may stop working in future.  If there's too much code for the question (see the minimal part of mcve) then sure.

Comment: @ArpitBansal, I don't know how to create jsfiddle. It is not a question of JavaScript. I just would like to place `down caret` top of the `Blue Bordered div`. If you are not clear, please ask me question.

Comment: @freedomn-m , I don't know how to create jsfiddle. It is not a question of JavaScript. I just would like to place `down caret` at the top of the `Blue Bordered div`. If you are not clear, please ask me question.  I would like to have a view like this   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgiSy.png. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For number, there is another solution that uses the `input` with type `number`

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Remind Number" name="remind_number" class="form-control" type="text" id="remind_number">
```

Another way, I remove usage of font-awesome and create triangle by pure CSS

```js
// add a javascript function to change the value of the input when clicking the caret
// get the input element
var input = document.getElementById("remind_number");
// function to modify the value of the input
function addValue(value) {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) + parseInt(value);
}
```

```css
.qty {
  width: 200px;
}

#remind_number_wrapper {
  float: left;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.up {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.down {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="qty">
   <div id="remind_number_wrapper">
     <input placeholder="Remind Number" name="remind_number" class="form-control" type="text" id="remind_number" value="0">
   </div>
   <div id="buttons">
     <!-- add className 'action_btn' to easier to style button in the same place-->
     <div class="action_btn" id="plus_remind" onclick="addValue(1)">
        <i class="up"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="action_btn" id="minus_remind" onclick="addValue(-1)">
        <i class="down"></i>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ChickenSoups. Your later solution has issue. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu What is the problem did you found? I run my code snippet and see nothing weird! Note that, I intended to use `fa-caret-up` icon  in the `minus_remind` div

Comment: Please see the image & click `fa-caret-up` where shown in image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gEN4.png . It is decreasing value instead of increase. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. So, I had updated the second approach by removing the usage of font-awesome. I draw two triangles by pure CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is somewhat unclear, if I understood you correctly, check out the example below to see whether it is what you want or not.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.qty {
    position: relative;
}
.new {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#plus_remind, #minus_remind {
    margin: 0;
    height: 24px;
    width: 22px;
    font: 33px/1 Arial,sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#plus_remind {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#minus_remind {   
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input {
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="qty">
   <input placeholder="Remind Number" name="remind_number" class="form-control" type="text" id="remind_number" value="25">
   <div class="new">
     <div onclick="document.getElementById('remind_number').value-=-1;" class="" id="plus_remind">
        <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
     </div>
     <div onclick="document.getElementById('remind_number').value-=1;" class="" id="minus_remind">
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
     </div>
  </div>
```